# Hover Effects to show Image

Tags: css

Is there any way that we hover on a TEXT and an image will shown. For example,
my name is ABC and my Country in DGF so when someone hover on ABC or DGF , an image will be shown.

Something like [this](http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/uhqlD) but it is not working in my webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Hide the image inside `#show-img` by default, then using the `:hover` psedo class change the display to block as given below

```
#show-img {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;   
}

#show-img img{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}

#show-img:hover img {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QMgV5/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="example">
  Hover over me
  <img src="example.com">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.example img {
  display: none;
}
.example:hover img {
  display: inline;
}
```